# Redux store state from React component's props does not reflect redux store's state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I have a react component that has 3 input fields and a button. 
The component is connected to a redux store. 
There is an action creator that makes a web API call to get the user's locational information and changes the state in the redux store.
The `onClick` event of the button in the form has a `handleOnClick` handler, which calls the action to update the store's state, and then it calls `setFormData` to update the values in the input fields to change the input fields' values.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setLocation} from "../actions/location.js";

const LocationForm = ({location, setLocation}) => {
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    city:"",
    state:"",
    country:""
  })
  
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
  }
  
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setLocation();
    console.log(location) //!! output: {city:"", state:"", country:""}
    const {city, state, location} = location;
    setFormData({...formData, city, state, location})
  }

  const {city, state, country} = formData;

  return (
    <form>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}/>
      <label>
        City:
        <input name="city" value={city} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      </label>
      <label>
        State:
        <input name="state" value={state} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      </label>
      <label>
        Country:
        <input name="city" value={country} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  location: state.location
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setLocation})(LocationForm);
```

**Problem:**
From what I could figure from the `console.log()` in the `handleOnClick`, the state of the  `location` object passed down from the redux store still has empty string as values for the keys(city, state, country). But the state in the redux chrome devtool does show that the state for location has changed and they have the right values. **How come the location object in the component's props does not reflect that?**  Do I need to use a `useEffect` hook to update the `location` object in the component's props?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: handleOnClick is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). It is not clear what you want the code to do and why you call a redux action without parameters but do expect a user to fill out a form.

Comment: The redux action makes an axios request and gets the locational data back using the user's IP address. Then it will dispatch an action to call the respective reducer function to update the state for location in the redux store. I want to fill the input fields with the users' locational values when they click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor changes of the `location` property, you have to use a hook, here is an example:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setLocation} from "../actions/location.js";

const LocationForm = ({location}) => {
  
  ..
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location)
    const {city, state, location} = location;
    setFormData({...formData, city, state, location})
  }, [location]);
  
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setLocation();
  }

  ..
}
```

The function passed as the first argument to `useEffect` is called every time any of the elements of the array passed as the second argument change.

Here, each time `location` changes, `setFormData` is called with the new values in `location`.

Comment: `setLocation` is not dispatched, just called as a function.. if this version works, then I don't think you need redux at all here...

Comment: @Aprillion In newer version of **redux** `bindActionCreators` is called by default. [More details](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object)

Comment: @Aprillion Oh, my bad, the problem is that the OP was calling the `setLocation` from `../actions/location.js` not the one from `props`. I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a mapDispatchToProps anonymous object to `connect`, but not using it in the component. Instead you were calling `setLocation()` as a normal function without dispatch. You need to call the prop, not the imported function like this:

```
const LocationForm = ({location, setLocation}) => {
    ...
      setLocation()
    ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setLocation})(LocationForm);
```

---

I would also recommend to give a chance to hooks which might be easier to understand IMHO:

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
...

const LocationForm = () => {
  const location = useSelector((state) => state.location)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  ...
  
  const handleOnClick => {
    dispatch(setLocation)      // if setLocation = (dispatch) => ...
    // dispatch(setLocation()) // if setLocation = () => (dispatch) => 
    ...
```